# AEM Adaptive Form Table Component Issues

Tags: adobe, aem, experience-manager

We've been getting some issues when using the OOTB table component(/libs/fd/af/components/table) on Adaptive forms. These are the issues I found so far:

After adding the table on an AF, replacing the text field to static text in a table cell causes the text in the static text object not to be editable.
When overlaying the component, basic functionality such as adding rows and columns doesn't work anymore
Environments:

Linux Ubuntu & Mint:

- AEM 6.3 with latest service pack(AEM-6.3.2.0)...Forms package(AEM-FORMS-6.3.2.1-LINUX)

Windows 10:

- AEM 6.4...Forms package(AEM-FORMS-6.4-WIN)

I am able to reproduce both issues on both AEM 6.3 and AEM 6.4 on both Linux and Windows.

Comment: What do you mean by text in the static text is editable. It works fine in my instance AEM 6.3. The static text remains fixed whereas other fields are editable.

Comment: The static text isn't editable after replacing textfield object with a static text object. That's what I meant....question edited...excuse the grammar errors I had before.

Answer (score 0):

AEM UI cannot resolve this. You need to go to crx repository and manually modify the xml file to remove  the jcr:title and hideTitle attribute for that element, for example:

```
<tableItem1633623930762
jcr:lastModified="Thu Oct 07 2021 14:59:34 GMT-0400"
jcr:lastModifiedBy="admin"
jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
sling:resourceType="fd/af/components/guidetextdraw"
_value="&lt;p style=&quot;text-align: right;&quot;>XXX:&lt;/p>"
colspan="2"
guideComponentType="true"
guideNodeClass="guideTextDraw"
name="tableItem16336239307621633623931747"
textIsRich="true"/>
<tableItem1633623930764
jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
jcr:title="Text box"
sling:resourceType="fd/af/components/guidetextbox"
colspan="2"
guideComponentType="true"
guideNodeClass="guideTextBox"
hideTitle="true"
name="tableItem16336239307641633623931758"/>
```

See the first elment, it is Text and removed jcr:title and hideTitle attribute.

Comment: the XML I mean .content.xml